# Get QGraphicsItem by mouse position in QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to connect two `QGraphicsItems` by *straight line* (`QGraphicsLineItem`); by clicking with middle mouse button on first object, then hover on second object and after I release it, it should draw line between them.

This is function that should connect these items.

```
void GraphicsBlock::connectBlocks(GraphicsBlock *block)
{
    GraphicsConnect *connection = new GraphicsConnect(); //Class with QGraphicsLineItem
    connection->line->setLine(QLineF(this->pos(), block->pos()));
}
```

I am working on one scene and I've got problem with finding second block by mouse position. Function `mousePressEvent`  should work with this code:

```
if(event->button() == Qt::MiddleButton)
    Connecting == true;
```

and after that `mouseReleaseEvent`

```
if(Connecting)
{
    //Get object by mouse position here
    //this.connectBlocks(..)
    Connecting = false;
}
```

I tried `scene->itemsAt(mouse.x(), mouse.y(), QTransform())` and

`scene->items(QPointF(mouse.x(),mouse.y())` but it always returned **empty list**.

EDIT:
This is how application should work, blue ellipse is clicked port, now i should drag (still mouse down) to another port and release mouse.

[image: Application image]

Comment: The items that are selected are the circles and the circles to join must belong to different ports. I am right?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, you are right

Comment: The blocks are always made up of a rectangle and 3 circles in the topLeft?

Comment: @eyllanesc For now yes, there can be one to five ports

Comment: I think we need more info on this. Are these shapes (rect and circles) aggregated inside a custom `QGraphicsItem` derived class? Show us the implementation. I also assume you have your own class which inherits from `QGraphicsView`. Is this correct? Is it where you handle mouse events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this with

```
QGraphicsItem *item = scene.itemAt(mapToScene(event->pos()), QTransform());
```

in function `mouseReleaseEvent`